# Values are float numbers but still `NaN`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I keep getting a `Nan`, is there some missing part in my code? The values that I have are pure float numbers, like, 79.00, 12.00 etc. Besides, I have written a long version of this code before, and I get the right answer but when I changed it to this shorter one, it gives me a `NaN`

*long-version of the code*

```
function tblcheckboxes(){
    var a, b, c ... v = 0;
    if ($('#tcbx1').is(":checked")) {
         a = parseFloat($("#tcbx1").val(), 10);
    }
    if ($('#tcbx2').is(":checked")) {
         b = parseFloat($("#tcbx2").val(), 10);
    }
    if ($('#tcbx3').is(":checked")) {
         c = parseFloat($("#tcbx3").val(), 10);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if ($('#tcbx23').is(":checked")) {
         v = parseFloat($("#tcbx23").val(), 10);
    }
    var total = a + b + c ... + v;
    $('.txt7').val(total.toFixed(2)); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tcbx1').click(function(){
                tblcheckboxes();
        });
        $('#tcbx2').click(function(){
                tblcheckboxes();
        });        
        $('#tcbx3').click(function(){
                tblcheckboxes();
        });
        ...
        ...
        ...
        $('#tcbx23').click(function(){
                tblcheckboxes();
        });
});
```

*currently codes*

```
function tblcheckboxes() {
    var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v = 0;
    var vars = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v]; // store in an array for easier access

    var total = 0; // initialize total so it can be added while looping through the elements

    for(var x = 1; x <= 23; x++) {
        if($("#tcbx" + x).is(":checked")) {
            vars[x - 1] = parseFloat($("#tcbx" + x).val(), 10);
        }
        total = parseFloat($(total).val(), 10) + vars[x - 1];
    }

    $(".txt7").val(total.toFixed(2));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 23; i++) {
        $("#tcbx" + i).click(function() {
            tblcheckboxes();
            grandtotal();
        });
    }
});

$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
  //change input #grandtotal value according check/uncheck checkboxes
  $(".txt7").val(function() {
    //declare a variable to keep the sum of the values
    var sum = 0;
    //using an iterator find and sum the values of checked checkboxes
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      sum = parseFloat($(sum).val(), 10) + parseFloat(~~$(this).val(), 10);
    });
    return sum;
  });
});

//here change the value according on checked checkboxes on DOM ready event
$(".txt7").val(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    sum = parseFloat($(sum).val(), 10) + parseFloat(~~$(this).val(), 10);
  });
  return sum;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oeojr93j/)

Comment: can you post your html? or recreate in a fiddle?

Comment: Looks like `a`, `b`, and `c` start out `undefined` and unless all the if statements are run, at least one will still be `undefined`. Adding `undefined` to anything produces `NaN`.

Comment: To expand on @AlexanderO'Mara's comment, you have to assign a value for each var individually. In your example, only `v == 0`

Comment: [*parseFloat*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) doesn't take a second argument (I presume you think it needs a radix), use just `parseFloat(string)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var a, b, c, ..., v = 0;
```

doesn't initialize all the variables. It initializes `v` to `0`, but all the other variables are undefined. That needs to be:

```
var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, ..., v = 0;
```

Or you can do:

```
var a, b, c, ..., v;
a = b = c = ... v = 0;
```

I suggest you reconsider using separate variables for everything, and use an array. You can then use a loop that iterates over all the inputs, and sets the corresponding element to either `0` or the input value.

Comment: i have tried declaring a variable individually and still gets `NaN`

Comment: have you checked whether `parseFloat()` is returning `NaN`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, why not **use** it? The *tblcheckboxes* function can be something like:

```
var total = 0;

$('input[id^=tcbx]').each(function(cb){total += cb.checked? Number(cb.value) : 0});

console.log(total);
```

Comment: You can also use the selector `input[id^=tcbx]:checked`

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize every single var, because when you write this:

```
var a, b, c ... v = 0;
```

all the variables except `v` are null at this point, and when you do this:

```
if ($('#tcbx1').is(":checked")) {
     a = parseFloat($("#tcbx1").val(), 10);
}
```

if `$('#tcbx1').is(":checked")` is false then `a` still undefined, and you can't do this:

```
var total = a + b + c ... + v;
```

so instead do this:

```
var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0 ... v = 0;
```

**EDIT:**  [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) does not take two arguments, but still works. Consider change that, another thing is probably `$("#tcbx1").val()` has numbers but maybe letter inside. Verify that the values are pure numbers or at least if the checkboxes values contains letters they must be at the end of the value:

```
parseFloat("12.3s", 10) // returns 12.3
parseFloat("s12.3s", 10) // returns Nan
parseFloat("12.3", 10) // returns 12.3
parseFloat("12.3") // returns 12.3
```

**EDIT:** thank you for the jsFiddle link, i saw this:

```
for(var x = 1; x <= 23; x++) {
    if($("#tcbx" + x).is(":checked")) {
        vars[x - 1] = parseFloat($("#tcbx" + x).val(), 10);
    }
    total = parseFloat($(total).val(), 10) + vars[x - 1];
}
```

check that when your code hits:

```
if($("#tcbx" + x).is(":checked"))
```

again `vars[x - 1]` is undefined, but you are still trying to call the `+` operator over it, it wont work. Not sure what are you trying to do, but the easy way should be this:

```
for(var x = 1; x <= 23; x++) {
    if($("#tcbx" + x).is(":checked")) {
        vars[x - 1] = parseFloat($("#tcbx" + x).val(), 10);
        total += vars[x - 1];
    }
}
```

and the ... well why don't you look at this:  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oeojr93j/1/)

Comment: this is correct, but its almost an exact copy of Barmar's answer and almost 15 mins later..

Comment: yeah, he forgot to explain the `if` conditions. cause it's part of the answer: why variables are still NaN when he calls the `+` operator over the variables. Of course if some the checkboxes are not `checked` then some of the variables will stay `undefined`

Comment: @jeniffer, why don't you try to debug it using [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) and check that the variables `a, b, c, v` are numbers on the last line `total = a + b + c ... + v` with a [breakpoint](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints), it is pretty easy